# To get highest run scorer

Tags: c#, .net

there is text file contains following data:

```
sachin tendulkar(*) 101
rohit sharma 121
sourav ganguly 83
mahendra singh dhoni(*) 99
virat kohli(*) 53
```

I want highest among them with `*` marks with name and score and also for without `*` marks with name and score

```
string input = "sachin tendulkar(*) 101,rohit sharma 121,sourav ganguly 83,mahendra singh dhoni(*) 99,virat kohli(*) 53";
        string[] name = input.Split(',');
        foreach (string sr in name)
        {
            if (sr.Contains('*') == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (string sr in name)
        {
            if (sr.Contains('*') == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are working with comma-separated line, if your text file contains every record in a separate line?

Read line, trim end, check if it contains '*', split that line (delimiter is space), take the last - that will be the score. And compare it with the previous line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(){
        yield return "sachin tendulkar(*) 101";
        yield return "rohit sharma 121";
        yield return "sourav ganguly 83";
        yield return "mahendra singh dhoni(*) 99";
        yield return "virat kohli(*) 53";   
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int highestScore = 0;
        string lineWithHighestScore = "";

        foreach (var str in ReadLines())
        {
            if (false == str.Contains("*")) continue;

            var fields = str.Split(new [] {" ", "\t"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int score = int.Parse(fields[fields.Length-1]);

            if (score > highestScore)
            {
                highestScore = score;
                lineWithHighestScore = str;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(lineWithHighestScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can help Chandan Varma by adding a minimal code example.